# How to initialize a UIButton's titleLabel font in a segue?

Tags: ios, uibutton, initialization, uilabel, segue

I have two `UIViewController`s `vc1` and `vc2`. The second view controller has a `UIButton` property `originalButton`.

In the segue from `vc1` to `vc2` I make a copy of `originalButton` for animation purposes (`buttonCopy`). The problem is that the titleLabel of `buttonCopy` has another font than the `originalButton` (the standard `UIButton` font).

Obviously this is because in the segue the `originalButton`'s titleLabel has not been completely initialized yet.

Calling `NSLog(@"%@",originalButton.titleLabel.font)` before copying the button has the side effect that the correct font is set for the titleLabel and subsequently `buttonCopy` will show up with the correct font.

But it seems ridiculous to use an `NSLog()` call just to initialize a button`s titleLabel font. There must be another way to achieve this. How?

---

**Edit:** This is the code where I copy the original button in my custom segue:

```
- (void)perform {

    ...

    // load view to initialize button
    [destinationViewController view];

    // the following line fixes the problem due to side effects
    NSLog(@"%@",destinationViewController.originalButton.titleLabel.font);

    // copy buttons
    // (using NSKeyedArchiver because UIButton does not support the copy method)
    NSData *archivedData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject: destinationViewController.originalButton];
    NSData *copy = [archivedData copy];
    UIButton *buttonCopy = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:copy];

    ...

}
```

Comment: Are you making the copy within `-prepareForSegue:sender:`? Can you show your code?

Comment: No, I make the copy in the `-perform` method of the (custom) segue.

Answer (score 1):

You can replace the call to `NSLog` by this statement:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", destinationViewController.originalButton.titleLabel.font];
```

This has the same effect on loading the font, but it does not output any log messages.

Answer (score 0):

You could try copying the button on `-prepareForSegue:sender:` like this:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
  id vc2 = [segue destinationViewController];
  [vc2 setOriginalButton:[vc1Button copy]];
}
```

You may replace `id` with the VC class name and add a `*` to make a pointer, if class is known.

Comment: That won't work as the `-prepareForSegue` method is called even _before_ the segue is performed i.e. before `-perform` is called. When the button's titleLabel has not yet been initialized in the `-perform` method it's pointless to try the same thing before.

Comment: Is `-perform` in VC1 or VC2?

Comment: Neither nor. It's in the custom segue class (see above).